# What Chrome data is kept in which files in the profile folder?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

I am trying to uncover anything useful from my corrupted Chrome profile (as Chrome doesn't sync a lot of things, like extensions local data, etc.) and I'm not sure what I should or should not copy.

There was a useful feature in the old Opera browser - it showed in what files it kept its various browsing data:

[image]

but I can't seem to find similar info for Chrome.

Comment: Chrome will sync extensions and local data provided you log into your Google Account.

Comment: It's syncing only a small amount of extensions data. It's definitely not syncing local storage and indexedDB and some other extension data. It's never syncing my Tab Outliner, Session Buddy, Tampermonkey and a lot of other extensions data.

Comment: Extension data is an entirely different beast.

Comment: @MelodyNelson - What did you end up doing? I face a similar predicament - http://superuser.com/questions/951095/understand-structure-of-chrome-user-profile-data-to-transfer-to-new-pc-os-avo

Comment: @Alex S - Basically I just gave up on the issue and still using new profile I had to create after corruption of the old one. I'm using chrome sync, and still have some crucial data from old times, like passwords, bookmarks etc.

Comment: @Alex S - At first I was trying to investigate every file and make some automated backup/transfer tool (for every local data that is left out of sync), but didn't have enough time or enthusiasm.

Comment: @Alex S - I still have an unfinished draft of my article about the subject, with descriptions of files, their purpose, are they synced, etc. I can show it to you, but it is not complete or even edited, my english can be pretty bad at times, and chrome file structure could change over the past year. Here is the text: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TDU7mJG-USa4d5OXHPLk03AwYaqpuBvrVSxypTBs4NM/edit?usp=sharing  there can be helpful links at the bottom.

Comment: @Alex S - I wasn't aware of the recent issues described in your question - I remember the only bad thing that ever happened to me with (not corrupted) profile copy-paste to new PC - passwords were protected, and were overwritten with empty values because I use sync.

I see that you also did a good research on the matter. If you don't mind I'll try to contact you via comments sometime in the future if I'll continue my project.

Comment: @MelodyNelson - Nice. I've collected lot of such data in a document as well :) It is a pain to deal with this stuff. I offloaded passwords using lastpass & nirsoft chromepass + keepass. Cant trust chrome for that. Working on the rest.

Comment: @MelodyNelson - By the way. Thank you. I will also try to upload the document I have after cleaning it.